# User account Mapping with IP Address in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I want to map the User (`Saad`) with IP `192.168.1.1`.

If user `Saad` tries to log in from IP `192.168.1.2`, then SQL Server should not allow access to the database.

Similarly user `Ali` is only allowed to access database from IP `192.168.1.2` and restricted by other IPs.

Mysql allowed to do this. How can we do this in SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2019?

Regards,
Saad

Comment: You can't map logins to IP address in SQL Server.

Comment: Firewall only allowed the IPs not restrict the Users with IP

Comment: You could potentially write a [`Logon Trigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15)  that checks the identity of the person logging in and `CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address')` and aborts the logon. Be careful as bugs in your code can stop anyone connecting - including you to fix the bug

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to do this. You can still achieve this using LOGON triggers. [Read more on Logon Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15)

1. Maintain user and corresponding IP address combination in a table.
2. Figure out the login using [ORIGINAL_LOGIN()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function
3. Figure out the IP Address using [EVENT_DATA()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eventdata-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as mentioned below in the [MSSQLTips link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6103/sql-server-logon-trigger-examples/)

[image]

4. Now, you need to rollback the login, if it is different from expected IPAddress, login combination